# Navigation Bar Across Multiple Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I've separated my views into multiple storyboards to make managing the project as a team much easier. The only problem is that I want to have the navigation bar across all of my different view controllers. I embedded the first view controller in a navigation controller which added the navigation bar. In my second storyboard, I wanted to constrain a view to the navigation bar, however, since this view controller isn't embedded in a navigation controller, there isn't anything to constrain the view to. I put a navigation bar without a navigation controller to constrain to, however, when I perform the segue from the first storyboard, this results in two navigation bars. How do I make this so that I can constrain the view to the navigation bar without having two of them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just constrain to the top layout guide.  This will respect the navigation bar at run time if it is present.

Comment: @Paulw11 how did I not think of that? Haha thanks so much man

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your problem. I guess that you want to use ONE navigation bar to constrain many UIViewController in different Storyboard. Here is my answer.

Step 1: Set up Storyboard ID in each UIViewController

[image: Storyboard ID]

Step 2: push new UIViewController

```
func switchNextView() {
    let storyboardName:String = "xxxxxx"
    let storyboardId:String = "xxxxx"

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = 
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) as! 
        UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go from on view controller to another by three way:-

First using segue as you are already doing

second You can Present your view controller by

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Third You can Navigate View controller by

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```